# EJB client not able to connect to EJB stateful bean deployed on JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jndi, remote-client

I have used eclipse to create a EJB project and have created 2 classes as below.

```
package com.abhijit.ejbs;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface TestEJBRemote {

    public void addElement(int a);
    public void removeElement(int a);
    public List getElements();


}
```

the actual EJB as below -

```
package com.abhijit.ejbs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class TesEJB
 */
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class TestEJB implements TestEJBRemote {

    List <Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public TestEJB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void addElement(int a) {
        myList.add(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeElement(int a) {
        myList.remove(a);
    }

    @Override
    public List getElements() {
        return myList;
    }

}
```

This EJB is then deployed on the JBoss AS 7 and it runs wihtout any errors..I see this message in the console -

```
**java:global/EJB1/TestEJB!com.abhijit.ejbs.TestEJBRemote
java:app/EJB1/TestEJB!com.abhijit.ejbs.TestEJBRemote
java:module/TestEJB!com.abhijit.ejbs.TestEJBRemote
java:jboss/exported/EJB1/TestEJB!com.abhijit.ejbs.TestEJBRemote
java:global/EJB1/TestEJB!com.abhijit.ejbs.TestEJB
java:app/EJB1/TestEJB!com.abhijit.ejbs.TestEJB
java:module/TestEJB!com.abhijit.ejbs.TestEJB**
```

Now , I am creating a 2nd Eclipse Java project and writing a simple java remote client code as below --

```
package com;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.abhijit.ejbs.TestEJB;
import com.abhijit.ejbs.TestEJBRemote;

public class EJBClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestEJBRemote values; 

        try {
            System.out.println("----");

            final Hashtable<String, String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
            jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

            //tried with rmi:  also .. not working....
            jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ejb://localhost:1099");

            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

            values = (TestEJBRemote)ic.lookup("java:global/EJB1/TestEJB!com.abhijit.ejbs.TestEJB");
            System.out.println("---" + values.getElements());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Tried with various combinations in the lookup() but when I run this java client code which would run in a separate JVM, its not working ..I am getting this error -

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.EJBClient.main(EJBClient.java:25)
```

I am sure it must be something to do with the jndi parameters..But I am not getting what it is...

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for Wildfly 8, 9 and 10.

### 1. Add required dependency `wildfly-ejb-client-bom`

You need to add the dependency `wildfly-ejb-client-bom` to your project.

In case you are using maven you can add the following dependency to your `pom`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Info use other versions for wildfly 8 (`8.2.1.Final`) or 9 (`9.0.2.Final`).

### 2. Create a `jboss-ejb-client.properties`

Add to your `resources` folder a `jboss-ejb-client.properties` and add the following content.

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

### 3. Create your initial context

You need to create the initial context as follows.

```
final Hashtable<String, String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<>();
jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
```

### 4. Lookup remote business interface

Finally you can do a lookup for your stateful session bean.

```
TestEJBRemote remote = (TestEJBRemote) context.lookup("ejb:/EJB1/TestEJB!" + TestEJBRemote.class.getName() + "?stateful");
```

**If you want to do a lookup for a stateless bean you have to remove `?stateful`.**

---

Unfortunately, the latest wildfly docs are a mess, and they don't provide a working solution. But you can find a working hello world example under [ejb-remote: Remote EJB Client Example](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/ejb-remote).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to get connected is wrong.

The following should be the format to connect to the remote ejb:

```
// Create a look up string name
String name = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName
            + "/" + beanName + "!" + interfaceName;
```

I contributed the following to SO Documentation.

---

## Setting up EJB with JBoss AS 7.1

**1. Overview**

In this article we are going to discuss how to get started with Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB). We will use JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final, but you are free to use any server of your choice.

**2. Maven Dependencies for Bean**

In order to use EJB make sure you add the latest version of it to the dependencies section of your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you add the JBoss dependencies properly as we will be using JBoss as our application server in this tutorial.
In the later part of the tutorial we will discuss in details on how to setup the maven build for the project.

**3. EJB Remote**

Let's first create the the Bean Interface called HelloWorldRemote.

```
public interface HelloWorldRemote {
    public String getHelloWorld();
}
```

Now we will implement the above interface and name it as `HelloWorldBean`.

```
@Stateless
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorldRemote {

    public HelloWorldBean() {
    
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getHelloWorld(){
        return ("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Note the `@Stateless` notation on top of the class declaration. It denotes a stateless session bean.

**4. Maven Setup for Remote Bean**

In this section we will discuss how to setup maven to build and run the application on the server.

Let's look at the plugins one by one.

*4.1.  Compiler Plugin*

The maven-compiler-plugin is used to compile the sources of our project.

Here we have used the version 2.3.1 of the plugin with the source and target JDK set to 1.7 under configuration.

We have defined these settings as properties inside  tag and referring it through ${property}.

```
<version.compiler.plugin>2.3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
<!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
```

*4.2 The EJB Plugin*

This plugin generates Bean file as well as the associated client jar.

We have specified the ejb version as 3.2 and the generateClient property is set to true which generates the client.

*4.3 Deploying in JBoss*

The jboss-as-maven-plugin is used to deploy, redeploy, undeploy or run the application in JBoss AS 7.

In this configuration we specify the build file name same as the project build filename which is by default of the form artifactid-version in our case `ejb-remote-1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

*4.4 Required Maven Dependencies for EJB*

jboss-javaee-6.0 defines the version of JBoss’ Java EE 6 APIs we want to use.

JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including a Bill of Materials (BOM).

A BOM specifies the versions of a stack (or a collection) of artifacts. We specify this in  tag so that we always get the correct versions of artifacts. The type of this dependency itself a pom which contains the required dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>${version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

*4.5  Annotations*

The following will get the annotations dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

*4.6 EJB version 3.2*

In the following piece of code we get the latest version of the specifications:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

To run the above project in a JBoss server we need to first run:

```
mvn clean install
```

Then we need to deploy it to a running JBoss server by running the following maven command:

```
jboss-as:deploy
```

Now you should see the jar file being deployed in the jboss server.

Alternatively you can copy the available jar from the target folder in the project and paste it in the webapp folder of the server.

**5. Setting up the Client Project**

After creating the remote bean we should test the deployed bean by creating a client.

First let's discuss the maven setup for the project.

*5.1 Maven Plugins used*

The maven-compiler-plugin is used to compile the sources of your project.

We specified jdk 1.7 version for source and target classes.

Our a client is a Java program, to run it we use the `exec-maven-plugin` which helps to execute system and Java programs. We need to specify the executable (i.e. java), classpath, and the java class (com.baeldung.ejb.client.Client).

The classpath is left empty because the plugin includes the necessary classpath arguments based on the dependencies provided.

*5.2 Maven Dependencies for EJB3 client*

In order to run EJB3 client we need to include the following dependencies.

We depend on the EJB remote business interfaces of this application to run the client. So we need to specify the ejb client jar dependency. The  tag with value “ejb-client” is used to specify this project’s dependency on the EJB client jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.theopentutorials.ejb3</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejbmavendemo</artifactId>
    <type>ejb-client</type>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The dependencies `jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec`, `jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec`, `jboss-ejb-client`, `xnio-api`, `xnio-nio`, `jboss-remoting`, `jboss-sasl`, `jboss-marshalling-river` have scope as runtime because these are required run time and not during compile time.

The dependencies **jboss-javaee-6.0** and **jboss-as-ejb-client-bom** under dependencyManagement have scope as import. This is used to include dependency management information from a remote POM into the current project. These remote POMs are provided by JBoss which contains the necessary dependencies for running the client.

*5.3 JBoss EJB Client properties*

Create a file under “src/main/resources” and name it as jboss-ejb-client.properties.

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

**6. Creating the Client Class**

First we create a ClientUtility class:

```
public class ClientUtility {
    private static Context initialContext;
    private static final String PKG_INTERFACES = "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming";

    public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        if (initialContext == null) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, PKG_INTERFACES);
            initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);
         }
        return initialContext;
    }
}
```

Now let's create the actual Client class that will consume the bean that we deployed in the server:

```
public class Client {
    
    //The lookup method to get the EJB name
    private static HelloWorldRemote doLookup() {
        Context context = null;
        HelloWorldRemote bean = null;
        try {
            // 1. Obtaining Context
            context = ClientUtility.getInitialContext();
            // 2. Generate JNDI Lookup name
            String lookupName = getLookupName();
            // 3. Lookup and cast
            bean = (HelloWorldRemote) context.lookup(lookupName);
 
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bean;
    }
 
    private static String getLookupName() {
        
         // The app name is the EAR name of the deployed EJB without .ear suffix.
         // Since we haven't deployed the application as a .ear, the app name for
         // us will be an empty string
         
        String appName = "";
 
        
         // The module name is the JAR name of the deployed EJB without the .jar
         // suffix.
        String moduleName = "ejb-remote-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT";
 
        
        // AS7 allows each deployment to have an (optional) distinct name. This
        // can be an empty string if distinct name is not specified.
        String distinctName = "";
 
        // The EJB bean implementation class name
        String beanName = "HelloWorldBean";
 
        // Fully qualified remote interface name
        final String interfaceName = "com.baeldung.ejb.tutorial.HelloWorldRemote";
 
        // Create a look up string name
        String name = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName
                + "/" + beanName + "!" + interfaceName;
        
        return name;
    }
}
```

The Client class consumes the bean and outputs the result.

**7. Conclusion**

So we have created an EJB server and a client which consumes the service. The project can be run on any Application Server.